# looping from database and no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I encounter a strange problem when trying to alter values from a Hash. I have the following setup:

```
def index

data, total = Role.with_filtering(params, current_holding_company)

data.each do |total_user|
  total_user = { total_user: RoleUser.where(role_id: data[:id]).group(:user_id).count.to_s }
  data[:total_user] = total_user 
end

respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render json: { data: data, total_count: total }.to_json, status: 200 }
end

end
```

When I execute this code I get: "TypeError: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer" . What am I doing wrong?

data is output from database, so my goal is i want to add total_user in every record with add new key and value into data

Answer (score 1):

This might not completely solves your issue but hopefully will guide you to the correct path.

In ruby the error `TypeError: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer` usually happens when you miss treat an array!

lets suppose you have

```
numbers = [1,2,3]

#now

numbers[0]
# > 1

numbers[2]
# > 3

#But

numbers[:1]
# throws TypeError: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer
```

So, you must be passing a symbol on an array [] operator by mistake

One way to debug this kind of issues is by checking class type of your objects, something like this in the consol

```
data.class
# > Array (for example)
```

Answer (score -1):

try this....

```
def index

data, total = Role.with_filtering(params, current_holding_company)

data.each do |total_user|
  total_user = { "total_user" => RoleUser.where(role_id: data[:id]).group(:user_id).count.to_s }
  data[:total_user] = total_user 
end

respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render json: { data: data, total_count: total }.to_json, status: 200 }
end

end
```